# Iterator method that returns value of parameter index

Tags: java, iterator

Im making iterator method( iterator( int index) that goes through a list of nodes. This particular method is going to return a iterator that behaves in a way that first call on the method next() will give the value of the index parameter. This is my first time with iterators so any help is appreciated!

```
  private class DoublelinkedlistIterator implements Iterator<T>
  {
    private Node<T> p;
    private boolean removeOK;


    private DoublelinkedlistIterator()
    {
      p = head;         // p is first in the list
     removeOK = false;  

    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {

        if(p.neste != null )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public T next()
    {

      Node<T> q = p;

      p = p.next; // go to next
      removeOK = true;
      return q.value; // return current value


    }

    public void remove() // in the making
    {

     removeOK = false;
    }

  } // class DoublelinkedlistIterator

  public Iterator<T> iterator()
  {
    return new DoublelinkedlistIterator();
  }

  public Iterator<T> iterator(int index) // its this one I need help with
  {


     next();
  }
```

Comment: What's your question exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply create the iterator and call next until you're at the correct index:

```
public Iterator<T> iterator(int index) {
    Iterator<T> it = new DoublelinkedlistIterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < index && it.hasNext(); i++, it.next());
    return it;
}
```

Note that if `index` is more than the length of your list, the iterator will not point to any element, but will be in a state where `hasNext()` returns `false`.